# Confirmation email Contact Form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I use the Contact Form 7 plugin on my site, now I have a task to send a confirmation email after sending the data. But I can not find in the documentation how to do this without creating an extra field.

**My solution:**

1. I created an additional field "Confirm email"
2. In the plugin settings, turned on Mail (2) and configured so that the email was sent

everything works perfectly. But is it possible to make it so that without an additional field sends a email? with different text?

"Thanks for your reply"

Answer (score 1):

Hook into `wpcf7_mail_sent` action, it fires after the mail is successfully sent.

```
function wpse_368498_cf7_mail_sent( $contact_form ) {

    //Your confirmation code here

}
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'wpse_368498_cf7_mail_sent' );
```

Comment: Can I call a shortcode in function.php? for to run another contact form

Comment: @Bavarius could you please explain your question a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect to another URL after the form is submitted. See: https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

Here, you could run your own custom script that sends out a custom email.

Comment: I think this is not the right decision.